# find all plane of symmetry of hyperbolic paraboloid

Tags: analytic-geometry, symmetry

Hi i need a little help to find all plane of symmetry of the  hyperbolic paraboloid. The equation is $x^2-y^2=z$.  I know that "standard" planes are   $x=0$ , because if i replace $x$ with $-x$ the equation does not change and $y=0$ for the same reason . My question is how can i say if there are more planes  of symmetry of this equation  ?( i mean "crooked" planes (i used a translator for this word)  Is there a way to find all plane of symmetry for an equation? thanks a lot

Comment: If you want to “find” all of the planes of symmetry, you need a definition of plane of symmetry.  What definition are you using?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang the standard definition , a plane that thanks to a reflection  around it  can send the paraboloid in the paraboloid .

Comment: @MatthewLeingang ù Should i maybe study the intersection of hyperboloid with axes , study the simmetry and so  find the plane ?

Comment: OK, so pick a generic plane $ax+by+cy=d$.  Take a point $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ on the surface (so $x_0^2-y_0^2 = z_0$), and compute the coordinates $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ of the reflection of this point in the plane.  These will depend on $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$, $x_0$, $y_0$, and $z_0$.  For which values of $a$, $b$, $c$, $d$ is $x_1^2-y_1^2 = z_1$?

Comment: @MatthewLeingang i have tried to do this but i have a lot of calculus (maybe i made an error...) the reflection of $(x_0,y_0,z_0)$ should be $(x_0+2t,y_0+2t,z_0+2t)$ where t is $-ax_0-by_0-c_z0+d/(a^2+b^2+c^2)$  but then if i try to substitute this point and use the condition i get two conditions and one of two is very difficult .

Comment: Yeah, that sounds right!  At this point you should look at the diagram again and use the known solutions to simplify the general solution set.  Keep in mind that $a$, $b$, $c$, and $d$ are only unique up to a constant multiple, so you'll get an extra parameter.

Comment: @MatthewLeingang Hi here I am again, i tried to look at the diagram of the figure , the thing that i have noticed maybe is that the origin has to be fixed but I don't think this can help me :( is there something from the diagram that i must see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a mostly complete answer which I have thought way too long on. First, use homogeneous coordinates so that we can say the surface has equation $X^TQX=0$, where $X = \begin{bmatrix} x & y & z & 1 \end{bmatrix}^T$ and
$$
    Q = \begin{bmatrix} 2 &  0 &  0 & 0 \\
                        0 & -2 &  0 & 0 \\
                        0 &  0 &  0 & -1 \\
                        0 &  0 & -1 & 0 \end{bmatrix}
$$

A (projective) linear transformation $A$ preserves the surface if for all $X$,
$$
    X^TQX = (AX)^T Q (AX) = X^T (A^TQA) X
$$
which would mean $A^TQA = Q$.  I want to say that $A^TQA=Q$ is necessary as well as sufficient, and I believe one can use the fact that $Q$ is invertible to prove that detail.

Now if $A$ is a reflection, $A^{-1} = A$, so $A^TQA = Q$ is equivalent to $A^TQ = QA$.  What is $A$?  From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformation_matrix#Reflection_2), if a plane has equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$, where $a^2+b^2+c^2=1$, the transformation of projective space which reflects in the plane has matrix equation $X' = AX$, where
$$
    A = \begin{bmatrix} 1 - 2 a^2  & - 2 a b & - 2 a c & - 2 a d \\ - 2 a b  & 1 - 2 b^2 & - 2 b c & - 2 b d \\ - 2 a c & - 2 b c & 1 - 2c^2 & - 2 c d \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}
$$
So $QA = A^TQ$ is equivalent to
$$
\left[\begin{matrix}2 - 4 a^{2} & - 4 a b & - 4 a c & - 4 a d\\4 a b & 4 b^{2} - 2 & 4 b c & 4 b d\\0 & 0 & 0 & -1\\2 a c & 2 b c & 2 c^{2} - 1 & 2 c d\end{matrix}\right]
= \left[\begin{matrix}2 - 4 a^{2} & 4 a b & 0 & 2 a c\\- 4 a b & 4 b^{2} - 2 & 0 & 2 b c\\- 4 a c & 4 b c & 0 & 2 c^{2} - 1\\- 4 a d & 4 b d & -1 & 2 c d\end{matrix}\right]
$$

These matrices are equal when each pair of corresponding entries are equal.  but the entries below the diagonal are redundant with ones above the diagonal, and the entries along the diagonal are tautologies.  So there are at most six equations to work with:
\begin{align*}
    -4ab &= 4ab \tag{1.2} \\
    -4ac &= 0   \tag{1.3} \\
    -4ad &= 2ac \tag{1.4} \\
     4bc &= 0   \tag{2.3} \\
     4bd &= 2bc \tag{2.4} \\
    2c^2-1 &= -1 \tag{3.4}
\end{align*}
The equation label $(m.n)$ comes from the $(m,n)$th entry of the matrices.  Remember also that $a^2+b^2+c^2 = 1$.

Now to solve this system.  First, by $(3.4)$, $c=0$.  Therefore $a^2+b^2 =1$.  If we square both sides of $(1.4)$ and $(2.4)$ and add left and right sides, we get $4(a^2+b^2)d^2 = (a^2+b^2)c^2$.  Since $a^2+b^2=1$ and $c=0$, we are left with $d=0$ as well.

Since $ab=0$ by $(1.2)$, either $a=0$ or $b=0$.  So it looks like there are four solutions for $(a,b,c,d)$: $(\pm1,0,0,0)$ and $(0,\pm1,0,0,0)$.  But it's more like two, since the first two solutions correspond to the same plane, and generate the same matrix $A$, and same for the last two.  So the unique solutions are:

- $(a,b,c,d) = (1,0,0,0)$, which gives the plane $x=0$ and the symmetry $x' = -x$, $y' = y$, $z'=z$.
- $(a,b,c,d) = (0,1,0,0)$, which gives the plane $y=0$ and the symmetry $x' =x$, $y'=-y$, $z'=z$.

*Exercise.* Find the planes of symmetry of the other quadric surfaces (e.g., the hyperboloids, elliptic paraboloids, cones, etc.) using this method.  The only change will be the matrix $Q$.

Comment: Hi really really thanks , that's strange... i stopped to think at this problem and today i started again to think at it !! I agree with you your solution is very detailed and clear but i have only one last question why is $a^2+b^2+c^2=1 $? i didn't understand this also before . Thanks again ;)

Comment: We're trying to parametrize the set of all planes in space.  A plane can be described by a point and a normal vector.  Scaling the normal vector doesn't change the plane it determines, so you can add in a constraint that the  normal vector has unit length.

Answer (score 0):

Changing sign of either x or y retains the surface equation.
So this hyperbolic paraboloid has two planes of symmetry
$$ z-x,\; z-y\;.$$

Next take y=0. you get z= x^2. It curves up to your right and left.

Take x=0. you get z= -y^2. It curves down towards and away from you.

There is no other even powered term, so no other symmetry possibility.

So it is not convex but a saddle point.

Sketch the warped surface.

[image]

If z=0 factors are x=y and x=-y. These are level straight lines. "col" paths between mountains.

Try to sketch a similar surface $z = 2 x y $ also for some more insight.

Comment: thanks for answering , i don't know the reason of th first part, why changing the sign of $x$ or $y$ tell me that planes are $z-y$ and $z-x$

Comment: The mirror effect. If y does not change sign then mirror plane of symmetry is the xz plane.

Comment: Hi sorry to bother you , I know my question is stupid, I am tired maybe, I agree with you but still don't know where the equation $x-z=0$ comes from.

Comment: Sorry. It is not an equation. It is the plane spanned by the X and Z axes. Angle XOZ is 90 deg at the origin.

Comment: Ok sorry again, I was looking in my problem for  cartesian equation of planes, that's why I asked you the equation, is there a way?

Comment: Yes. For the above Y=0. is equation of XZ plane.

Comment: Sorry to bother you I have only 1 last question. Can i just say that planes of symmetry of this hyperboloid are in the  end x=0,y=0 and x=+-y bacause the hyperboloid s symmetric to z axes and x=+-y are simmetry axes of hyperbola on plane xy ?

Comment: No. Hypar is *NOT* a surface of revolution. Symmetry planes are  *ZX, ZY*.  I have re-sketched it

Comment: Can you explain how “there is no other even power term” implies that there is no other symmetry possible?  For instance, the circular paraboloid $z = x^2+y^2$ has infinitely many symmetries despite only two squared terms.

Comment: Used only cartesian reflection planes $ Oxy,Oyz,Ozx$ as there are no coefficients for $ xy,yz,zx $  coupling terms in $ z=x^2-y^2$